# Change css code with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

Here I have a big problem.

First I have a function distance(latt) which return me a distance in KM.
Now I want to change css code to be width of `.timedistance div = distance(latt)`.

I do this:

```
hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.line').show();
    var latt = $(this).attr("lat");
    $(this).find('.timedistance').width(distance(latt)); 
    $(this).find('.timedistance').show(); 
},function () {
    $(this).find('.line').hide();
    $(this).find('.timedistance').hide();    
});



$(".draggable").each(function () {
    $(this).append("<div class='timedistance'></div>");
    $(this).append("<div class='line'></div>");
});
```

Comment: yes its defined and correct

Comment: What `it(distance(latt))` returns?

Comment: syntactically it is wrong

Comment: return decimal number etc. 121.23435345

Comment: syntactically , where is wrong ?

Comment: can you post the complete code, there are mismatches in the brackets

Comment: you need to share your html and more script if you want a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `parseInt` like,

```
var latt = $(this).attr("lat");
$(this).find('.timedistance').width(parseInt(distance(latt))); 
$(this).find('.timedistance').show();
```